# Is there a more user friendly alternative to Net::HTTP for interacting with REST APIs?

Tags: ruby, http, rest

Net::HTTP can be rather cumbersome for the standard use case!

Answer (score 20):

If you only have to deal with REST, the [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) library is fantastic.

If the APIs you're using aren't completely RESTful - or even if they are - [HTTParty](http://railstips.org/2008/7/29/it-s-an-httparty-and-everyone-is-invited) is really worth checking out. It simplifies using REST APIs, as well as non-RESTful web APIs. Check out this code (copied from the above link):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

class Representative
  include HTTParty
  format :xml

  def self.find_by_zip(zip)
    get('http://whoismyrepresentative.com/whoismyrep.php', :query => {:zip => zip})
  end
end

puts Representative.find_by_zip(46544).inspect
# {"result"=>{"n"=>"1", "rep"=>{"name"=>"Joe Donnelly", "district"=>"2", "office"=>"1218 Longworth", "phone"=>"(202) 225-3915", "link"=>"http://donnelly.house.gov/", "state"=>"IN"}}}
```

Comment: My only issue with HTTParty is th it returns a hash instead of parsing the XML and returning an array of 'Representaive' objects with attribute accessors. 

Instead of returning the Hash from find_by_zip, i built an array of Representative objects myself and returned that.

Answer (score 5):

[rest-open-uri](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rest-open-uri/) is the one that is used heavily throughout the [RESTful Web Services](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529260/) book.

```
gem install rest-open-uri
```

Example usage:

```
response = open('https://wherever/foo',
                :method => :put,
                :http_basic_authentication => ['my-user', 'my-passwd'],
                :body => 'payload')

puts response.read
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm a big fan of [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client), which does just enough to be useful without getting in the way of your implementation. It handles exceptions intelligently, and supports logging and auth, out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

[HyperactiveResource](http://github.com/lukegalea/hyperactiveresource/wikis) is in its infancy, but it's looking pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use: http://rubyforge.org/projects/restful-rails/.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at asplake's (i.e. my) described_routes and path-to projects/gems on github (which I can't seem to link to from here.  Path-to uses HTTParty, but rather than hard-coded URLs like some of the other answers to this question, it uses metadata provided by described_routes.  There are several articles describing these gems at positiveincline.com, of which the most relevant to your question is [Nested path-to/described_routes and HTTParty](http://positiveincline.com/?p=173).

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's always ActiveResource, provided you're on Rails :)